# Okhttp timeout exception after 10 secs even though I have given 30 minutes as timeout.

Tags: java, android, forms, android-asynctask, okhttp

Here is the code

```
public class InitializeBuilderOkhttp extends OkHttpClient{

    OkHttpClient client;

    public OkHttpClient InitializeBuilderOkhttp() {

        client = new OkHttpClient();
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        builder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        client = builder.build();
        return client;

    }
}
```

As you can see, I have given 30 minutes as connect timeout, read timeout and write timeout.

I am initializing and declaring the above class

```
OkHttpClient client = new InitializeBuilderOkhttp();
```

in the oncreate method of the activity.

In the doInBackground method of async task class I am calling a rest api with the above okhttp client.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("userId", userId)
                .addFormDataPart("password", password)
                .addFormDataPart("datatype", "app")
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(params[0])
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What is wrong with this code?
Thanks for your time.

Note:- The timeout is 10000 ms or 10 secs which is the default timeout time for okhttp.After 10 secs the error is shown on the logcat.That is the timeout has not changed and it has remained the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
```

Make client in this way and use seconds unit instead of minutes. It will work.Hope it will help you.Do let me know if it works :)

Comment: So it wouldnt be a problem if 60 is replaced by 6000?Then the time will be 100 mins.Also how to have unlimited socket connection timeout?

Comment: yes you can replace time but give it in seconds I had this problem and I resolved this by changing my unit into seconds.

Comment: to make unlimited time is not a good idea at all. By doing this your app will wait like centuries if there is no response and it will freeze your UI. It complicates things.Better is to check for your response that your server replies in how many seconds after that for safety purposes add 10 seconds to it and make this as your timeout

Comment: Thank you buddy. Best of luck with your project. Happy coding :)

Comment: Worked like magic!